# How can we rotate an array to the left?

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

EX: I have an array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and an integer number `7`
It will rotate `7` spaces to the right like: `{4, 5, 1, 2, 3}`

I also have that array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and an integer number `-7`
It will rotate `7` spaces to the left like: `{3, 4, 5, 1, 2}`

I have rotated the array to the right by using:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
              result[(i+n) % data.length ] = data[i];
            }
```

But how can we rotate an array to the left?

Comment: The problem is because `a negative number modulo positive number will give a negative result`. In your case `(i+n)` will be negative if your `n` is negative...

Comment: Just to inform. if you are using List(not array) use the inbuilt function Collections.rotate(+ve no) to rotate right and Collections.rotate(-ve no) to rotate left.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rotating to the left by n is the same as rotating to the right by length-n.

Rotate right (for positive n):

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    result[(i+n) % data.length ] = data[i];
}
```

Rotate left (for positive n):

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    result[(i+(data.length-n)) % data.length ] = data[i];
}
```

This way you can avoid a modulo of a negative number.

If you want to input an integer n that rotates right if n is positive and left if n is negative, you can do it like this:

```
 int[] rotateArray(int n, int[] data)
 {
      if(n < 0) // rotating left?
      {
          n = -n % data.length; // convert to +ve number specifying how 
                                // many positions left to rotate & mod
          n = data.length - n;  // rotate left by n = rotate right by length - n
      }
      int[] result = new int[data.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          result[(i+n) % data.length ] = data[i];
      }
      return result;
 }
```

Comment: that's good, handle rotating to the left by converting it to the right!! In this case, rotating 3 spaces (n == 3) to the right is equivalent rotating 2 space (n == -7) to the left

Answer (score 5):

In case rotate to the left, you can use this to avoid a modulo of a negative number:

```
int[] data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] result = new int[data.length];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    result[(i + (data.length - 2)) % data.length] = data[i];
}

for (int i : result) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use linkedlist to achieve the same.

```
Integer[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

        LinkedList<Integer> ns = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        int rotate=3;
        if(rotate<0)
            rotate += arr.length;

        List<Integer> leftlist = ns.subList(0, rotate);
        List<Integer> rightlist = ns.subList(rotate, arr.length);

        LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        result.addAll(rightlist);
        result.addAll(leftlist);

        System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate an array named `a[n]` with `n` as the size of an array and `d` as the number of rotation (in your case `d=7`), you can use this code:

```
    d = d % n;
    for(int i=d;i<n;i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<(d);i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
```

This code will print the array elements in order after the left rotation is performed. If you want you can store it in another array, or you can show array elements as shown in the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete java program for n left rotations of an array.

```
public class ArrayRotation {
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n,k;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of array: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        int[] a = new int[n];
        System.out.print("Enter the "+n+" elements in the list: ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of left shifts to array: ");
        k = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Array before "+k+" shifts: ");
        display(a);

        solution(a,k);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Array after "+k+" shifts: ");
        display(a);
    }

    public static void solution(int[] a, int k){
        int temp=0, j;
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            temp = a[0];
//          j=0;                    // both codes work i.e. for loop and while loop as well
//          while(j<a.length-1){
//              a[j]=a[j+1];
//              j++;
//          }   
            for(j=0;j<a.length-1;j++)
                a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j]=temp;
        }           
    }

    public static void display(int[] a){
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] array, int elements, int rotations) {


    // i = checks number of rotations
    for (int i = 0; i < rotations; i++) {

        int first = array[0];
        int last = array[elements - 1];

        // j = rotates each element
        for (int j = 0; j < elements; j++) {

            // check if at first index
            if (j == 0) {
                array[elements - 1] = first;
            }

            // check if at last index
            if (j == (elements - 1)) {

                // if at last index: make element in index before last = to last element
                array[elements - 2] = last;
            } else {
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
            }

        }


    }

    return array;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest answer I could come up with.
Notice that you need to compute `rotations % length` so that your program is robust to a number of rotations greater than the size of your array.

```
static int[] rotateLeft(int[] arr, int rotations) {
        int length = arr.length;
        int[] result = new int[length];

        rotations = rotations % length; // robust to rotations > length
        int position = length - rotations; // compute outside the loop to increase performance
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result[(position + i) % length] = arr[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below approach putting the array into a new array in its new position.

```
    int length = a.length;
    int[] newArr = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
        int newPosition = i - d; // d is the number of rotation
        if (newPosition < 0)
            newPosition = length + newPosition;
        newArr[newPosition] = a[i];
    }
```

Initially i wanted to swap into the same array using the below approach but it did not work all the cases. For example where 2 array elements are being swapped due to rotation. So newPosition and position keep on pointing to each other. Hence rest of the array is not moved.
Not sure if it is possible to rotate array with O(n) complexity in the same array.

```
    int length = a.length;
    int position = length-1;
    int temp = a[position];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        int newPosition = position - d;
        if (newPosition < 0)
            newPosition = length + newPosition;
        int cache = a[newPosition];
        a[newPosition]= temp;
        temp = cache;
        position = newPosition;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Javascript:
n is the number of elements and r is the number of rotations.
a is the array.

```
function rotate(a,r,n)}
for(var i = 0; i<r; i++){
 var aa = array[0] // 

for (var j = 0; j < n-1; j++){ 
array[j] = array[j+1] // 
}
array[n-1] = aa      // 
 }
return a
} 

 var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(rotate(array,1,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Left rotation using lambda expression.
int []  ar = {1,6,7,5,9,1,34,7};
        int shift =2;
int[] posAr = IntStream.range(0, ar.length).map(i->(ar[(i + (ar.length + shift)) % ar.length])).toArray();

//You can print the data
Arrays.stream(posAr).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmIvv.png)

Show code:

```
    if(a.length==0 || a.length==1)
        return a;

    int r=d%a.length;
    int A[]=new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        if((i+r) >= a.length)
            A[i]=a[i+r-a.length];

        else 
            A[i]=a[i+r];

    }

    return A;
```